# Nested FQL query suddenly returning OAuthException

Tags: facebook-fql

This FQL query, which used to work, is now returning an OAuthException with code 1 and message "An unknown error has occurred."

```
SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

I have read_stream permission, and the following queries work as expected:

```
SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid=###
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()
```

I've also tried adding `LIMIT 10` at the end in case there was a timeout issue, but that didn't help.

Do I need additional permissions? Is there an error in the query?